# JOIN three tables even if one is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get values from three tables even if one is empty.
Since I would be able to use an if else statement depending if the `following.follow_id` row is empty or not.

```
SELECT user.id, user.username,user.email, userdetails.profile_img, following.follow_id 
FROM user 
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id 
JOIN following ON user.id = following.follow_id 
GROUP BY user.id;
```

For now it only gives me the value if there is a value on row `following.follow_id`.
But I would be able to get all the result from the user_id even if there's an empty table.

Any clues ?

Comment: I think you want an `outer join`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing "JOIN", which implies "INNER JOIN", by "LEFT JOIN" should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you would need to use an OUTER join to accomplish this.

The reason for it is that when you just say JOIN, this is actually interpreted as an INNER JOIN, in which case there will need to be a  match in all tables.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you're using an INNER join across these 3 tables.  What this means is that you will only get back rows that have corresponding rows in the other tables. That is, if a given user.id does not have a corresponding following.follow_id and userdetails.user_id, then that row will be left off.

If instead you use a LEFT JOIN (left outer join) from users to the other tables, I think you should have the results you're looking for.

For more on INNER vs OUTER joins, this question might be helpful:
[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)